# Enumerate behaves differently with beamer 3.42

Tags: beamer, enumerate

The following is produced by `beamer` version 3.41 with `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
    {\usetheme{Rochester}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{enumerate}[1]
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And with `beamer` version 3.42 the following:

[image]

The latter output is so, well, ugly, that it's probably a bug. While waiting for a bug fix (?), how can I temporarily fix this so that I get the output produced by `beamer` 3.41?

Comment: Note that as I've said in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/453, the `Rochester` theme is supposed to have 'boxed' item labels (though of course not with bits of the text missing!)

Comment: @JosephWright What does it mean that `Rochester` is "supposed" to have boxed labels? It didn't until version 3.42. In fact, one of the reasons I always liked and used `Rochester` is because it didn't box the item labels.

Comment: The Rochester theme does `\useinnertheme{rectangles}`, so it meant to have square markers. You see that (correctly) if you use a standard `enumerate` without the label customisation.

Comment: @JosephWright Oh, you may be right. I think I used to write `[1]` precisely to avoid those boxes. So that's no longer supposed to be an option with `Rochester`?

Comment: Not really, no: the fact that setting the 'mini template' zapped the boxes _was_ a bug. You probably want `\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]` after loading the `Rochester` theme to override this one aspect.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, this will also change the labels in `itemize` from a box to an arrow, which I am not a fan of.

Comment: You'll need to change the templates one-by-one then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant difference between v3.41 and v3.42 is that `enumerate mini template` was added in the `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` to the line

```
\defbeamertemplateparent{enumerate items}{enumerate item,enumerate subitem,enumerate subsubitem,enumerate mini template}
{}
```

---

Workaround:

- keep a modified version of `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` in your working folder
- use beamer's own mechanism instead to set the enumeration symbol

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
    {\usetheme{Rochester}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

{
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\alph{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item much smaller margin
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the style of the item labels, this change is deliberate. The `Rochester` theme loads the `rectangles` inner theme, and that was always *supposed* to have 'square' item labels. One can see that in a normal `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The fat that the text in the current case looks a bit 'squeezed' is because the size of the squares is hard-coded. One might therefore make them a bit bigger, for example by applying

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}
{%
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width3ex height2.2ex depth.8ex%
    \hskip-3ex%
    \hbox to3ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{fg}\insertenumlabel%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}
```

In terms of the alignment of items, there was a deliberate change of indent in the code which worked on the width of the 'mini template'. Thus with `(a)` and `1`, the widths were set differently. There are no code notes here, so I can only assume that the logic was that on any one slide, only one type of `enumerate` was expected. Thus a variation in indent was not expected to be an issue. As of v3.49, this code will be removed such that the indent is the same for all cases. (See [`beamer` issue 453](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/453)/ commit https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/5692a7d1983654a984f6f11d503e9913758768c0.) With this fix added, and the adjustment to the `enumerate mini template` setting, the output looks like
[image]

---

Note that if the presentation was using the mini templates purely to change the item label appearance, the correct approach would be to change the `beamer` template

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]