# Different output with \useinnertheme in Texlive 2017 and 2018 [beamer]

Tags: beamer, texlive-2018

The following code shows two differents outputs with TeXLive 2017 and Texlive 2018

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{With Texlive 2017}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]
  \item  aaaa
  \item  bbb
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[$\bullet$]
  \item  cccc
  \item  ddd
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why is there this difference?

[image: Here is the output with Texlive 2017]

[image: Here is the output with Texlive 2018]

Comment: There where some bug fixes in beamer for missing inheritance of templates that caused the change. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394481/beamer-and-enumerate-package/394503#394503 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386878/enumerate-behaves-differently-with-beamer-3-42/386916#386916

Comment: Thanks @samcarter . \setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{\insertenumlabel} do the job (but with a margin a little larger).